# JPA: Is there some way to implement inheritance for Embeddable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here is the example code:

```java
class Resource {
  Long id;
  @Embedded
  GPU gpu;
  CPU cpu;
}

abstract class GPU {
  String name;
  GpuType type;
}

class PhysicalGPU extends GPU {
}

class VirtualGPU extends GPU {
  private int partition;
}
```

I have an Entity `Resource` and it has a field `GPU` which is a superclass. It can be a `VirtualGPU` or `PhysicalGPU`. But JPA or Hibernate seems not support class inheritance for `@Embedded` fields. And it is ugly to create a single GPU type with no inheritance or create `PhysicalGPUResource` and `VirtualGPUResource` to implement the inheritance for a single field.

And I think as a descriptor of a `Resource`, make the `GPU` be an association in a seperate table (and give a `ManyToOne` relation in `Resource`) is also not a good practice but this will make the Inheritance available.

I did some search and I think right now the answer is no. But I still think this is a quite big requirement for the Hibernate ORM and it can be implemented in some framework like `MyBatis`, it is quite weird that Hibernate do not support this behavior. So maybe there is some other way to make this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think current the best way is using UserType. Follow the article [Custom Types in Hibernate and the @Type Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-custom-types) can be very helpful.

But I still don't know what is the advantage of the `CompositeUserType`.